# local variables in threading function in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

```
struct node
{
public:
    char *s;
    int up;
    node()
    {
        up = 0;
        s = new char[1000];
        memset (s, 0, sizeof(char) * 1000);
    }
    ~node()
    {
        delete [] s;
    }
    void insert()
    {
        s[up++] = 'a';
    }
};

void* test_thread(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
    node n;
    n.insert();
    printf ("%s\n", n.s);
    printf ("%x\n", &n);
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
    pthread_exit(0);
    //return 0;
}
```

supose this function will be executed by

```
pthread_create(&id1, NULL, test_thread, NULL);
pthread_create(&id2, NULL, test_thread, NULL);
```

and it is compiled by

```
g++ test_thread.cpp -o main -lpthread -g
```

its result is

```
a
40a001a0
a
40a001a0
```

In my Linux operator ,the address of node n in the two thread are the same!

I want to know why the address of node n in which the tho thread contains are the same?

Any answer is appreciated~~~

Thanks~~~

Comment: Do you think you could give some of the output of `gcc -s -o test.s -c   filename.c`? This looks like a weird optimization to me.

Comment: Can you show some sample output of the program?

Comment: Maybe by the time the second thread is started, the first one has already finished, and the second thread just happens to re-use the now freed memory? What happens if you make the function wait some time between `pthread_mutex_unlock` and `pthread_exit`?

Comment: Try to lock the mutex before the printf (after the insert).

Comment: BTW, your `memset` call looks wrong (why would you set the first 4 or 8 bytes of the memory to 0, depending on the size of the pointer?).

Comment: +DeadMG: i feel bad for my code too,  forgive me. +celtschk : i change it just now,thank you~~~; and i just tried to make the function wait some time between pthread_mutex_unlock and pthread_exit,but the result is same too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `sleep(1)` before you exit the thread. Now you should see two different addresses but the same output of `'a'`. (you would need `pthread_join` though).

Now if you want to print `'aa'` then you might have to define node in global space or define it in main.

With your current code the `lock`/`unlock` does not have any use but once you use the shared memory the 2nd thread can not write until the 1st thread has finished.

Answer (score 2):

The object 'node n' is stack-local, so each of the two threads has their own 'node'. This explains why each time you see only one 'a' intead of two of them.

By the time the second thread starts, the first one has probably already finished, including freeing the memory, so that the second thread gets the same memory block again, that explains the same address.

If you want both threads to work on the same 'node' you need to make it a global variable, or allocate one and pass the pointer as fourth argument to pthread_create() so that it will be passed on to test_thread().

Comment: Just want to add comment to asnwer. Adding `sleep` end of thread function (after mutex unlock) which guaranteed that threads are running at same time and output should be different.

Comment: Even though I add sleep at the end of thread function `sleep(1)`, it is same too, i feel frustrated

Comment: @kaitian are you sure you put the sleep between the pthread_mutex_unlock() and the pthread_exit()? Also this will only make the addresses different, it doesn't solve the issue of each thread using it's own node.

Comment: +Seg Fault && +Torsten : `40a001a0 414011a0`, I understand what you too mean! Thank you very much~~~